OOP usage in Unity Game Engine
i've started to learn Unity and we were always using MonoBehaviour Parent and Child Classes. After that i realized that we need to use OOP with our projects. I know how can i create classes and objects in C# and i know essential functions for Unity. How can i learn combining both of them in order to create more advanced programes.
In other words, i don't get how we can create some Game Objects which are not applied to Monobehaviour class, and instantiate them to the scene. Do i need other Scripts which are related with Monobehaviour class for that?
If you can help me providing some guideline to learn OOP in Unity, i'ld really appretiate for that
:/ I might have explained my problem a little bit bad but this is where i actually have issues.
For Example, with following code i created Item Class and Inventory Class, lets say I'm going to add Sprites to my "Item" how can i handle with that in Unity? Wıth MonoBehaviours i can attach Script to the game objects and take sprite from the editor.
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class Item {
    public enum ItemType {
        None,
        Sword,
        HealthPotion,
        ManaPotion,
        PowerUpPotion
    }

    public ItemType itemType;
    public float amount;
}

// *******************************************************

using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class Inventory 
{
    public List<Item> ItemList;

    public Inventory() {
        ItemList = new List<Item>();

        AddItem(new Item {itemType = Item.ItemType.Sword, amount = 1});
        Debug.Log(ItemList.Count);
    }

    public void AddItem(Item item) {
        ItemList.Add(item);
    }
}


classes give you behaviours on objects, so, the object is almost irrelevant, you can still do inheritance with monobehaviours

For data assets that aren't necessarily code, but needs to be able to modify within the editor or store Unity objects (like Sprite), Unity has ScriptableObjects.
You can create a class that inherits from ScriptableObject:
public class Item : ScriptableObject {
    public enum ItemType {
        None,
        Sword,
        HealthPotion,
        ManaPotion,
        PowerUpPotion
    }

    public ItemType itemType;
    public float amount;
    public Sprite inventorySprite;
}

then you can Right Click (in Assets window) > Create > ScriptableObjects > [Classname] inside your assets folder, and edit or refer to them like any other Unity object.

OW, i tried it once and created an inventory system. But is it sustainable for all things; in other words am i gonna need other classes which are not inherited from Monobehaviour, or can i create almost everything with monobehaviours , scriptable objects etc.

You only need to inherit from ScriptableObject if you want to store them as a Unity asset. If you only need to store runtime data, you can just have a normal class/struct.

I GOT IT :D , thx so much, especially for your time

Note that in order to create a SO instance through the create menu as mentioned in this answer, you have to add the [CreateAssetMenu] attribute to the Item class. If you have many assets like this, you can use sub menus by specifying a menuName that contains slashes i.e. "Items/Item"

or data assets that aren't necessarily code, ... those are in particular code though ;) they are just not bound to a GameObject instance
